# Save CarrierWave Upload as Base64

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I would like to take an uploaded attachment from CarrierWave and save it as a Base64 string in my database table, as opposed to saving the path of the upload.

I have absolutely no idea where to start the process. I tried to create the following:

```
........

before_create :process_image


mount_uploader :image_upload, ImageUploader

.......

attr_accessible :name, :image_upload, :authentication_type

attr_reader :image

private
  def process_image
    if !self.image_upload.path.nil?
      self.image = Base64.encode64(file.open(self.image_upload.path).read)
      self.image_upload = nil
    end
  end
```

However, during the upload I get the following error:

> NoMethodError (undefined method `image_upload_will_change!'

I am sure it's something trivial, however, it seems like I am the only one that wants to try this.

Comment: If you want to save image as Base64 then why you want to use carrirwave?

Comment: Maybe that's where my confusion lies. Don't I need carrierwave to actually do the upload? Or, can I bypass that, altogether?

Comment: If you only want to save images in Base64 then just save image information in field manually and avoid carrierwave as you do not need to upload image anywhere